# Bookmarklet to link custom font and test not working

Tags: testing, font-face, bookmarklet

I made a custom font and wanted to test it on websites so I wrote this bookmarklet. I hosted the font and stylesheet on my phone with the Simple HTTP  Server app.

```
javascript:(function()
{ var head = document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0];
var link=document.createElement('link');
link.rel = 'stylesheet';  link.href = 'http://192.???.?.????:????/elle/stylesheet.css';
link.type ='text/css';  link.charset = 'UTF-8';
head.appendChild(link);
document.body.style.fontFamily = "'elle-2aregular', sans-serif, georgia";
})()
```

Stylesheet

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'elle-2aregular';
src:url('http://192.???.?.????:????/elle/elle.woff2') format('woff2'),
url('http://192.???.1.????:????/elle/elle.woff') format('woff');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: The JS looks fine. Have you tried the `@font-face`  rule on a static HTMl page also running on your loacal server? If it doesn't  work also, there might be a server-side issue like file permissions or incorrect mime types. You might also try to load the font from a puplic server to ensure everythings fine with your font and font-face rule.

Comment: Yes, @font-face worked on a local test HTML document. I should try a public server. Thx

Comment: If you're running the bookmarklet script on a phone - it might also be blocked due to additional security measures. For instance most mobile browsers also block dispatched events when triggered on load - just an idea.

Comment: Unfortunately a public server gave the same results for mobile and desktop browser. I generated the .woff/.woff2 's from .ttf with FontSquirrel. You mentioned file permissions and mime types. I should learn more about that.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the font links in the stylesheet being blocked by the browsers. I got around this by embedding the fonts in Base64 code rather than linking to them.

[Font-Face and Base64 Data-URI](http://stephenscaff.com/articles/2013/09/font-face-and-base64-data-uri/)

Thank you @Herrstrietzel for the suggestions.